# Set font size in Opera

Tags: fonts, opera-browser

Opera Mini has an option to choose between small/medium/large font sizes. I tried to find this option in [the new Opera browser](http://www.opera.com/mobile/android) for Android, but couldn't.

Is there any way at all to set the font size for Opera?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any setting to change the font size. However, you can pinch-in and pinch-out to zoom.

Comment: Except you can't on sites that disable zooming. Those are the sites I want large fonts for.